# convert payment express asp.net webforms to mvc razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, payment-gateway

I need help to convert asp.net webforms to asp.net mvc razor any help will be appreciated.  I asked them for MVC razor equivalent and this the code they provided. I am not from a webforms background jumped onto razor directly.  I am able to create the forms, for user to put in the order.  The order is sent to the controller - and xml created but I not able to redirect to their page to display the payment api that takes the credit card details.

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;

// TODO: Note that you must set the following values in the web.config before running this page
//  <appSettings>
//      <add key="PxPayUserId" value=""/>
//      <add key="PxPayKey" value=""/>
//  </appSettings>

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

    //Determine if the page request is for a user returning from the payment page

    string ResultQs = Request.QueryString["result"];

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ResultQs))
    {
        string PxPayUserId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PxPayUserId"];
        string PxPayKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PxPayKey"];

        // Obtain the transaction result
        PxPay WS = new PxPay(PxPayUserId, PxPayKey);

        ResponseOutput output = WS.ProcessResponse(ResultQs);

        // Write all the name value pairs out to a table

        Table t = new Table();
        TableRow tr;
        TableCell tc;

        PropertyInfo[] properties = output.GetType().GetProperties();

        foreach (PropertyInfo oPropertyInfo in properties)
        {

            if (oPropertyInfo.CanRead)
            {

                tr = new TableRow();
                tc = new TableCell();

                tc.Text = oPropertyInfo.Name;
                tr.Cells.Add(tc);

                tc = new TableCell();
                tc.Text = (string)oPropertyInfo.GetValue(output, null);
                tr.Cells.Add(tc);

                t.Rows.Add(tr);

            }
        }

        Panel1.Controls.Add(t);

        // Sending invoices/updating order status within database etc.

        if (!isProcessed(output.TxnId) && output.valid == "1" && output.Success == "1")
        {
            // TODO: Send emails, generate invoices, update order status etc.
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Database lookup to check the status of the order or shopping cart
/// </summary>
/// <param name="TxnId"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
protected bool isProcessed(string TxnId)
{
    // TODO: Check database if order relating to TxnId has alread been processed
    return false;
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string PxPayUserId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PxPayUserId"];
    string PxPayKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PxPayKey"];

    PxPay WS = new PxPay(PxPayUserId, PxPayKey);

    RequestInput input = new RequestInput();

    input.AmountInput = txtAmountInput.Text;
    input.CurrencyInput = txtCurrencyInput.Text;
    input.MerchantReference = txtMerchantReference.Text;
    input.TxnType = ddlTxnType.Text;
    input.UrlFail = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path);
    input.UrlSuccess = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path);

    // TODO: GUID representing unique identifier for the transaction within the shopping cart (normally would be an order ID or similar)
    Guid orderId = Guid.NewGuid();
    input.TxnId = orderId.ToString().Substring(0, 16);

    RequestOutput output = WS.GenerateRequest(input);

    if (output.valid == "1")
    {
        // Redirect user to payment page

        Response.Redirect(output.Url);
    }
}


 }
```

Comment: web-forms and mvc/razr are two different technologies , you can't "Just convert" and aspx to a razr view

Comment: yes I was looking for guides from those who have done similar  but I have now solved the problem in this case you really do not have to do much coding